# Filters vector of custom struct

Tags: rust

I want to query and filter some ethereum addresses based on eth balances.

Here is the code I have so far:

```rust
let reserve_1 = "0xdf6764f41eb550f060aea6c852b822a49b53c6e2".parse::<Address>()?;
let reserve_2 = "0xb47936bbc484e56dda8b57440ca3c5459f495cf3".parse::<Address>()?;
let reserve_3 = "0x0133f9f460282d10c8db2d3376764412af57808c".parse::<Address>()?;
let reserve_4 = "0xa49a964d5345a9c8f7f6516c5aaee7a3dd1b7870".parse::<Address>()?;
let reserve_5 = "0x94c3857520e9151b34814fbf8b477368f4a97ea7".parse::<Address>()?;
let reserve_6 = "0x914f1f73f42c3aca3328d41210e32731a7f969c8".parse::<Address>()?;
let reserve_7 = "0x6005121a46bb3028872cf471faab92a08b2d0f5a".parse::<Address>()?;
let reserve_8 = "0x8e385bc51f7a5385604d8617c9ba2a40f9e5a387".parse::<Address>()?;
let reserve_9 = "0xab112ddda6d0196915618d605d909306e7c7ebd7".parse::<Address>()?;
let reserve_10 = "0x5e1c7f0ef930d79598f9fadbaca3c1bea400e6f7".parse::<Address>()?;
let balances = client
    .get_ether_balance_multi(
        &vec![
            &reserve_1,
            &reserve_2,
            &reserve_3,
            &reserve_4,
            &reserve_5,
            &reserve_6,
            &reserve_7,
            &reserve_8,
            &reserve_9,
            &reserve_10,
        ],
    None,
    )
    .await
    .unwrap();
```

`balances` has type `Vec<AccountBalance>`

```rust
pub struct AccountBalance {
    pub account: Address,
    pub balance: String,
}
```

I want to create an iterator to filer our balances , but something like this doesnt seem to work

```rust
let low_balances = balances.iter().filter(|n.balance| n < 10000000000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

n is the property name -- you instead move the property name to the actual function body (outside of the `| |`)

```rs
let low_balances = balances.iter().filter(|n| n.balance < 10000000000)
```